# In python, is it possible to create a 'shortcut' to a variable. So if variable changes, so does shortcut?

Tags: python

I am thinking of something like this.

```
a = shortcut(classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute)
print(a)
```

> 5

```
classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute = 10
print(a)
```

> 10

Motivation: I want to refer to attributes in python objects with lots of subobjects. Having shortcuts to these attributes would declutter the code.

Comment: No, it's not possible AFAIK.

Comment: No you cannot. You and something like `short = classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects` then use `short.attribute` everywhere instead of `classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute`

Comment: You could also define a function `def a(): return classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute` and then use `a()`

Comment: Are the "sub objects" the same every time? You could add a `@property` to `classObject` that returned the nested lookup

Comment: if you have to refer to deeply nested attributes frequently, there's probably something wrong with your design. You should refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of. If the attribute is a mutable container and the "changes" are objects being added to or removed from the container, then yes. You can get a reference to the container and see those changes.

```
classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute = []
foo = classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute
classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute.append(10)
print(foo)
```

In your example, you assign `10` which is not a container... but its parent is. You can get almost to a dot free life with

```
classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute = 10
foo = classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects
classObject.with.LotsOf.Subobjects.attribute += 1
print(foo.attribute)
```